# emacs-pinentry not working on emacs 28.0.50 and Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gpg

`Emacs-pinentry` is not working for me on `emacs 28.0.50` and Ubuntu 20.04, and I wonder why. I follow these steps:

1. In `/home/user`, do `git clone https://github.com/ecraven/pinentry-emacs.git`
2. Following the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32881/enabling-minibuffer-pinentry-with-emacs-25-and-gnupg-2-1-on-ubuntu-xenial), I put this in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
allow-emacs-pinentry
allow-loopback-pinentry
```

3. Tell `gpg-agent` to load this configuration with `gpgconf` in a shell: `gpgconf --reload gpg-agent`
4. In Emacs' `init.el` I write:

```
(use-package pinentry
    :config
    (setq epa-pinentry-mode 'loopback)
    (pinentry-start))
```

5. Following advice [here](https://github.com/ecraven/pinentry-emacs), I also include in my emacs dotfiles:

```
(defun pinentry-emacs (desc prompt ok error)
  (let ((str (read-passwd (concat (replace-regexp-in-string "%22" "\"" (replace-regexp-in-string "%0A" "\n" desc)) prompt ": "))))
    str))
```

The author of `emacs-pinentry` also says to set `GPG_AGENT_INFO` correctly inside Emacs, but I don't know what that means.

Maybe that's the missing bit for my setup to work. Thought I think to remember that on one or two occassions I did enter successfully the password for decrypting some entry in `.password-store` with `pass`. But on those occassions I entered the password blindly, without any prompt or feedback on the minibuffer. I kinda tried my luck and it worked. However, my expectation was to have a prompt on the minibuffer and some indication that I am typing, such as a string of stars.

Answer (score 1):

In the channel `#emacs` of the Discord channel `System Crafters`, a very nice indeed participant called `Ashraz` told me that:

- `pinentry-emacs` isn't necessary anymore.

  - which explains why `pinentry-emacs` didn't get an update for ~4 years.
  - Reason: `gpg-agent` has `allow-emacs-pinentry` nowadays, which tells the default `pinentry` program to use Emacs as `pinentry` (if it is running and the `pinentry` service has been started via `pinentry-start`).
  - Also `GPG_AGENT_INFO` shouldn't be necessary in `GPG 2.1` or higher.

So all you need to do is:

First, add the following lines in your `gpg-agent.conf`:

```
  allow-emacs-pinentry
  allow-loopback-pinentry
```

The second line allows Emacs to be used as pinentry even if Emacs originally asked the decryption.

Second, you need to adjust epa to use the loopback interface instead and start the server:

```
(setq epa-pinentry-mode 'loopback)
(pinentry-start)
```

For more information, see info pinentry and [Enabling minibuffer pinentry with Emacs 25 and GnuPG 2.1 on Ubuntu Xenial](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32881/)

Another interesting read is: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/keeping-secrets-in-emacs-gnupg-auth-sources

(Note that the process may be different for emacs version 26 and later; see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/68304)